# How to enumerate a constant array at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, constexpr, compile-time

I am trying to generate a hash at **COMPILE TIME** from a literal string (array of characters). For example:

```cpp
unsigned long long compiledHash = ComputeHash("literal string");
```

I am currently stuck on finding a way to enumerate all characters in the string and creating a unique hash. If I use a `for` loop like I would normally, the compiler won't generate the hash at compile time, which is not what I want.

I might of found a way to do so, but the compiler is stuck in an infinite loop when calculating the hash.

```
template <size_t _length, typename T, int n> struct CostructHash {
    unsigned long long Value;
    constexpr __forceinline CostructHash(const T(&str)[_length]) :
        Value(str[n] ^ n + (n > 0 ? CostructHash<_length, T, n - 1>(str).Value : 0)) {}
};

template<size_t _length>
constexpr __forceinline unsigned long long ComputeHash(const char(&str)[_length]) {
    return CostructHash<_length, char, _length - 1>(str).Value;
}
```

As you can see I use recursion to go through all characters in the string, but I must of messed up somewhere, because as I said the compiler freezes forever when it calls `ComputeHash`.

I understand that I must be missing the base case that stops the recursion, but as far as I understand `(n > 0 ? CostructHash<_length, T, n - 1>(str).Value : 0)` should do the job since I am always decreasing `n` by 1 and checking if `n` is bigger than `0`. So why is the recursion not stopping?

Also, there may be an easier way to do what I am trying?

Comment: The regular `for` loop should work. Can you show us your attempt that uses one? Also make the function `consteval`, the non-portable `__forceinline` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `Do you see the problem in the code` Yes. The template is infinitely recursive. You are missing the base case that stops the recursion.

Comment: You should tag this question with a specific C++ standard version if you have such constraints. Otherwise, as mentioned earlier, in modern C++, this is just a matter of tagging a garden-variety hash function with `consteval`, eg: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aTKxdjPMe

Comment: *If I use a for loop like I would normally, the compiler won't generate the hash at compile time* This is just wrong. Make a `constexpr` function, and as long as you pass in a compile-time value to it the result is calculated at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you see the problem in the code

The recursion is infinite because there is no base case for the template instantiations.

> but as far as I understand `(n > 0 ? CostructHash<_length, T, n - 1>(str).Value : 0)` should do the job since I am always decreasing n by 1 and checking if n is bigger than 0. So why is the recursion not stopping?

The template is instantiated before the compiler decides whether that branch will be taken. You have to use `if constexpr` instead of the ternary conditional, or you have to specialise the template for the base case.

> Also, there may be an easier way to do what I am trying?

This seems to work fine:

```
constexpr std::size_t
ComputeHash(std::string_view str) {
    std::size_t result = 0;
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for(auto c : str) {
        result += c ^ i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using `if constexpr` in a separate function worked, thanks!